# How to make a common listener in a class

Tags: android, listener

I have dynamically added a certain view (e.g. edit text, radio, and check box). How do I add a common listener to all views so that I can access the value in it (when it changes)?

Comment: What kind of listener?

Comment: @NicolasTyler change listener so that value on change can be accessed

Comment: Well each view type has different listeners, so you would have to assign different listeners to them.

Comment: What about creating a Custom Listener for the your custom event say on change...

Comment: You would then need to create a custom control for each control. And create a listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom abstract listener class which implements all the needed listeners by your different views.

For example,

```
public abstract class CustomListener implements OnCickListener, CheckedChangedListener....{


public void onClick(View view){
onEvent(view);
}

public void onCheckedChanged(View view){
onEvent(view);
}

public abstract void onEvent(View view);

}
```

Then in your class create an object of this customListener and add for all the views

Answer (score 1):

From the way you phased your question I will assume that you have not worked with this much, you most likely don't need to create a custom control or a custom listener.

You said you where adding controls dynamically, so it looked something like this:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
//editText setup...
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this)
//radioButton setup...
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
//checkBox setup...
```

You could then add listeners to that like this (optionally calling the changed method):

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
//editText setup...
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        changed();
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
//radioButton setup...
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changed();
    }
});
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
//checkBox setup...
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        changed();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have done the same. I thought their might be a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give the click event listener, just define the below code in oncreate method.

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
```

And your custom listener would be like this,

```
private OnClickListener clicklistener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnSubmit:
                // Do your code....
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```